# Stack and reshape Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Given a 4 2d array as below

```py
import numpy as np
    
t1=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]])
t2=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
t3=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
t4=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
```

May I know how to combine and reshape it to get the output as below

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 1. 0. 1.]
      [1. 0. 1. 1.]]
     [[0. 1. 0. 1.]
      [0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [1. 1. 0. 1.]]
     [[1. 0. 1. 1.]
      [1. 1. 0. 1.]
      [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [66]: t1=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]])
    ...: t2=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
    ...: t3=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
    ...: t4=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
In [67]: t1.shape
Out[67]: (3, 3)
In [68]: np.stack((t1,t2,t3,t4),axis=2)
Out[68]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Transpose of the array (also `np.stack((), axis=0)`) produces the same thing, but that is only because each of the (3,3) arrays are symmetric.

```
In [70]: np.array((t1,t2,t3,t4))
Out[70]: 
array([[[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, safe to say directly transpose will fail if we have asymmetrical last 2 dimension? I have not check this with large dimension thou

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(np.array([t1,t2,t3,t4]).T)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: t1=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]])
   ...: t2=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
   ...: t3=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
   ...: t4=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])

In [3]: np.array((t1, t2, t3, t4)).T
Out[3]:
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

The `.T` is equivalent to the `transpose` function.